# Not able to connect on Mongodb Atlas port

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm using an M0 GCP instance.

I can connect to the cluster using this string:

```
'mongodb+srv://my_user:my_pass@my_cluster-mbsnz.gcp.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

I'm trying to use another client where I need to pass host and port, but I can't connect.

I tried telnet to the port 27017, but for some reason I'm not able to connect directly on the port.

```
curl http://my_cluster-mbsnz.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my_cluster-mbsnz.gcp.mongodb.net port 27017: Connection timed out
```

or

```
telnet my_cluster-mbsnz.gcp.mongodb.net 27017
Trying 185.82.212.199...
^C -> After a long time waiting
```

What might be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+srv` urls use a DNS seed. On atlas, you can click into the cluster and you should be able to see the urls for your primary & your secondaries and use those urls to connect. You should also be able to use `nslookup` to get that info using part of that connection string, but it's probably simpler to just look up the urls through the UI.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

> In order to leverage the DNS seedlist, use a connection string prefix of mongodb+srv: rather than the standard mongodb:. The +srv indicates to the client that the hostname that follows corresponds to a DNS SRV record. The driver or mongo shell will then query the DNS for the record to determine which hosts are running the mongod instances.